# C# Entityframework core how to fluent map configure common property between multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a base class 'BaseCodeEntity' with following properties. I am using Entityframework fluent mapping to configure the properties. I want to  know how to map common properties. Currently i am doing something below which i can see is not proper way. Can anyone help me how to write in a proper way.

```
public abstract class BaseCodeEntity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

fluent mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyCode>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.CompanyCodeId);
    
        entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCenterCode>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.CostCenterCodeId);
    
        entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<DisciplineCode>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.DisciplineCodeId);
    
        entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
        });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<SubDisciplineCode>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.SubDisciplineCodeId);
    
        entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
    });     
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using derived classes in `modelBuilder` use base class, EF Core will automatically apply the rules to all derived classes model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseCodeEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.CompanyCodeId);

            entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsRowVersion();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this back in time, i needed to apply basic generic configurations for all my Entities and ValueObjects, but in a way that i dont repeat myself, so i did this:

```
public static class BaseEntityConfiguration
{
    static void Configure<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) where TEntity : Entity
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            builder.Ignore(x => x.Valid);
            builder.Ignore(x => x.Invalid);
            builder.Ignore(x => x.ValidationResult);
        });
    }

    public static ModelBuilder ApplyBaseEntityConfiguration(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var method = typeof(BaseEntityConfiguration).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods.Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Configure));

        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entityType.ClrType.IsBaseEntity(out var T))
                method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType, T).Invoke(null, new[] { modelBuilder });
        }
        return modelBuilder;
   }

    static bool IsBaseEntity(this Type type, out Type T)
    {
        for (var baseType = type.BaseType; baseType != null; baseType = baseType.BaseType)
        {
            if (baseType.IsGenericType && baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Entity))
            {
                T = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                return true;
            }
        }
        T = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, in your Context configuration call this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{           
    // Configuracao da entidade base
    modelBuilder.ApplyBaseEntityConfiguration();
           
    // Configuracao das entidades
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Of course i did this for all my value object and BaseEntity and AuditedEntity, but its all copy paste on this pattern.

Heres another example of a ValuObject that is mapped to a table, but can have multime Phone objects for the same Entity:

```
public static class ConfigurePhoneProperties
{
    public static void Configure<TEntity>(ModelBuilder builder) where TEntity : class
    {
        var phoneProperties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Phone));

        foreach (var prop in phoneProperties)
        {
            builder
                .Entity<TEntity>()
                .OwnsOne<Phone>(prop.Name)
                .Property(phone => phone.Number)
                .HasMaxLength(9)
                .HasColumnName(string.Format("{0}{1}", prop.Name, "Number"))
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Entity<TEntity>()
                .OwnsOne<Phone>(prop.Name)
                .Property(phone => phone.CountryCode)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnName(string.Format("{0}{1}", prop.Name, "CountryCode"))
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Entity<TEntity>()
                .OwnsOne<Phone>(prop.Name)
                .Property(phone => phone.AreaCode)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnName(string.Format("{0}{1}", prop.Name, "AreaCode"))
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }

    public static ModelBuilder ApplyPhonePropertyConfigration(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var method = typeof(ConfigurePhoneProperties).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods.Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Configure));
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Entity));

        var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList();

        foreach (var mutableEntityType in entityTypes)
        {
            var entityType = Type.GetType(mutableEntityType.Name + ", " + assembly.FullName);

            if (entityType is null)
                continue;

            if (entityType.GetProperties().Any(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Phone)))
                method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(null, new[] { modelBuilder });
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```